# jquery objects not allowing navigation item to be placed on the right side

Tags: jquery, css, html, coldfusion, positioning

I cannot get the right-facing arrow ("next") to sit on the right edge of either object.

I'm using `ScrollTo` and `SerialScroll` (had links to these but cannot post them).

Here's where the example of my problem is: http://www.palosverdes.com/sandbox/problem/divs.cfm

I'm using Coldfusion 4.5 to include each item separately.
The first item with the green buttons is at: http://www.palosverdes.com/sandbox/problem/serialscroll/extract.cfm

I was going to list where the second item is but I can only post two hyperlinks.

I've tried defining specific widths for each element and using `float: left` and `right` but I cannot seem to get it where I want it.

Comment: Yep, almost didn't even want to type it in there, horrid system

Comment: the issue probably isn't with the horribly outdated ColdFusion install, but can you upgrade to railo? It's free and almost certainly infinitely better than CF4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your includes are violating all kinds of HTML [validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.palosverdes.com%2Fsandbox%2Fproblem%2Fdivs.cfm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) rules. You can't embed `<html>` tags inside other `<html>` tags. A document should only contain one pair of `<html>` tags. The extract.cfm should only include the content within the `<body></body>` tags. You can move the script and css tags to the parent cfm `<head>`.

Comment: Ok, I corrected that part at least, but now I can see the problem with using two instances of the same jquery element.  There's all sorts of duplicate div id requests which probably isn't helping things.  Maybe I should just use a different jq element for one of them...

Answer (score -1):

A quick fix could be to change the markup - put floated elements (i.e. the right arrow) before whatever you wanted floated right of.

seeing as you floated the `.next` class ,you can change this

```
<a href="#" class="prev"><img src="images/left.png"></a>
<ul><!-- list items --></ul>
<a href="#" class="next"><img width="38" src="images/right.png"></a>
```

into this

```
<a href="#" class="prev"><img src="images/left.png"></a>
<a href="#" class="next"><img width="38" src="images/right.png"></a>
<ul><!-- list items --></ul>
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, it seems to have nestled it into the upper left of the scroller.  I've left it updated

Comment: looking at http://www.palosverdes.com/sandbox/problem/serialscroll/extract.cfm, you will need to position it properly, not unlike what you did with the .prev class (margin-top) and also make the container correct width (so the arrow doesn't fly all the way over to the right...)